# Emacs Go Lang Struct Align Text

Tags: emacs

In go we have structs like this:

```
type person struct {  
   firstname string  
   lastname string  
   age int  
   address string  

}
```

I want it to be aligned like this

```
type person struct {
   firstname string
   lastname  string
   age       int
   address   string

}
```

and stuff like

```
const (  
    constant1 int = 1  
    c2 int = 2  
    const3 int = 3  
)
```

to

```
const (    
    constant1   int = 1  
    c2          int = 2  
    const3      int = 3  
)
```

I know align-regexp should help here, but i am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `go-mode`? It will use `fmt` or `goimport` to format you code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am using go-mode and go-fmt both not doing the alignment

Answer (score 0):

`go-mode` should run `gofmt` or `goimports` if you put it in the save hook.

```
(use-package go-mode
  :config
  (when (executable-find "goimports")
    (setq gofmt-command "goimports"))
  (defun jpk/go-mode-hook ()
    (add-hook 'before-save-hook #'gofmt-before-save nil 'local))
  (add-hook 'go-mode-hook #'jpk/go-mode-hook)
  )
```

Comment: this does not work, i have a similar configuration on my init file, running gofmt directly on the buffer also does not work

Comment: What does the `*Messages*` buffer say?  Are there any errors?  Does gofmt work outside of Emacs?  Does it work with something like `M-! gofmt foo.go`?

Comment: It seems its problem with Emacs. When I cat the file on terminal or run Emacs in terminalmode, the alignment is proper, but with Emacs in GUI the alignment is not proper

Comment: If I'm going to guess, Emacs is getting started with a different `PATH` compared to the shell in the terminal.  I have to guess because you didn't say what errors, if any, are coming up.

Comment: On the Emacs GUI, M-x gives an output "this buffer is gofmted", it does other things like removing extra spaces, empty lines etc, just the alignment does not work

Comment: I get lines in `*Messages*` that say exactly what the command Emacs is running from its `gofmt` function:  `Calling gofmt: goimports (-srcdir /home/jpkotta/go/src/github.com/botlink/go-go-botbox/cmd/auth/main.go -w /tmp/gofmtpESVZm.go)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183039/discussion-between-jpkotta-and-pharaoh).